# GLSL uniform ivec doesn't set and has default (wrong) value when is being asked

Tags: c++, glsl

I have a scene with several GLSL programs (OpenGL 3.3). These programs use different shaders, which are similar, but (will) have some differences. And I have a uniform `ivec4 char1` named the same for all versions, which has the same meaning and value for all programs. This uniform is used in `dot1(...)` function, which is used in `main()` function within the shaders.

**fragment3d.glsl:**

```
#version 330 core

smooth in vec4 vertexPosition;
smooth in vec4 vertexColor;
smooth in vec4 vertexNormal;
out vec4 fragmentColor;

uniform ivec4 char1;
uniform float shineness;

float dot1(vec4 x, vec4 y)
{
    float result = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        result += char1[i] * x[i] * y[i];
    }
    return result;
}

void main()
{
    if (vertexNormal == vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    {
        fragmentColor = vertexColor;
    }
    else
    {
        vec4 lightDirection = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) - vertexPosition;
        float lightNormInverse = inversesqrt(dot1(lightDirection, lightDirection));
        lightDirection *= lightNormInverse;
        float diffuseCoefficient = dot1(lightDirection, vertexNormal);
        vec4 reflectedDirection = 2 * diffuseCoefficient * vertexNormal - lightDirection;
        diffuseCoefficient = abs(diffuseCoefficient);
        float specularCoefficient = max(dot1(reflectedDirection, lightDirection), 0.0);
        if (specularCoefficient > 0.0 && shineness > 0.0)
        {
            specularCoefficient = pow(specularCoefficient, shineness);
        }
        vec3 diffuseColor = clamp(vertexColor.rgb * diffuseCoefficient, 0.0, 1.0);
        vec3 specularColor = clamp(vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) * specularCoefficient, 0.0, 1.0);
        fragmentColor.rgb = diffuseColor + specularColor;
        fragmentColor.a = 1.0 - diffuseCoefficient * (1.0 - vertexColor.a);
    }
}
```

**fragment3d-new.glsl**

```
#version 330 core

smooth in vec4 geometryPosition;
smooth in vec4 geometryNormal;
smooth in vec4 geometryColor;
out vec4 fragmentColor;

uniform ivec4 char1;
uniform float shineness;

float dot1(vec4 x, vec4 y)
{
    float result = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        result += char1[i] * x[i] * y[i];
    }
    return result;
}

void main()
{
    if (geometryNormal == vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    {
        fragmentColor = geometryColor;
    }
    else
    {
        vec4 lightDirection = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) - geometryPosition;
        float lightNormInverse = inversesqrt(dot1(lightDirection, lightDirection));
        lightDirection *= lightNormInverse;
        float diffuseCoefficient = dot1(lightDirection, geometryNormal);
        vec4 reflectedDirection = 2 * diffuseCoefficient * geometryNormal - lightDirection;
        diffuseCoefficient = abs(diffuseCoefficient);
        float specularCoefficient = max(dot1(reflectedDirection, lightDirection), 0.0);
        if (specularCoefficient > 0.0 && shineness > 0.0)
        {
            specularCoefficient = pow(specularCoefficient, shineness);
        }
        vec3 diffuseColor = clamp(geometryColor.rgb * diffuseCoefficient, 0.0, 1.0);
        vec3 specularColor = clamp(vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) * specularCoefficient, 0.0, 1.0);
        fragmentColor.rgb = diffuseColor + specularColor;
        fragmentColor.a = 1.0 - diffuseCoefficient * (1.0 - geometryColor.a);
    }
}
```

The initialization C++ code is:

```
glUseProgram(0);
if (m_glProgram[GEOMETRY] != 0)
{
    glDeleteProgram(m_glProgram[GEOMETRY]);
}
if (m_glProgram[TRIANGLE] != 0)
{
    glDeleteProgram(m_glProgram[TRIANGLE]);
}
if (m_glProgram[TEXTURE] != 0)
{
    glDeleteProgram(m_glProgram[TEXTURE]);
}
GLuint vertexShaderGeometry = compileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertex, ss);
GLuint fragmentShaderGeometry = compileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragment, ss);
vector<GLuint> shadersGeometry = {vertexShaderGeometry, fragmentShaderGeometry};
m_glProgram[GEOMETRY] = compileProgram(shadersGeometry, ss);
glUseProgram(m_glProgram[GEOMETRY]);
m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_PROJECTION] = glGetUniformLocation(m_glProgram[GEOMETRY], "projection");   // Set in changeProjection(...)
m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_ORIENTATION] = glGetUniformLocation(m_glProgram[GEOMETRY], "orientation"); // Set in changeOrientation(...)
m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_MODE] = glGetUniformLocation(m_glProgram[GEOMETRY], "mode");               // Set here
m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_CHAR1] = glGetUniformLocation(m_glProgram[GEOMETRY], "char1");             // Set here
m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_SHANENESS] = glGetUniformLocation(m_glProgram[GEOMETRY], "shineness");     // Set here? For now it is hardcoded.
cleanProgram(m_glProgram[GEOMETRY], shadersGeometry);

if (m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_MODE] >= 0 && dim == 2)
{
    // TODO Add configuration for Poincare model.
    // For now, Beltrami-Klein is hardcoded.
    glUniform1i(m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_MODE], 1);
}
if (m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_CHAR1] >= 0)
{
    GLint char1[4];
    char1[0] = m_projected.chars(0);
    char1[1] = 1;
    char1[2] = m_projected.chars(1);
    char1[3] = m_projected.chars(1, 2);
    glUniform4iv(m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_CHAR1], 1, char1);
}
if (m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_SHANENESS] >= 0)
{
    // Add it to configuration. For now it is hardcoded.
    glUniform1f(m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_SHANENESS], 1.0);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (dim == 3)
{
    GLuint vertexShaderNew3d = compileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "vertex3d-new.glsl", ss);
    GLuint geometryShaderNew3d = compileShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, "geometry3d-new.glsl", ss);
    GLuint fragmentShaderNew3d = compileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "fragment3d-new.glsl", ss);
    m_glProgram[TRIANGLE] = compileProgram({vertexShaderNew3d, geometryShaderNew3d, fragmentShaderNew3d}, ss);
    glUseProgram(TRIANGLE);
    m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_PROJECTION] = glGetUniformLocation(m_glProgram[TRIANGLE], "projection");   // Set in changeProjection(...)
    m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_ORIENTATION] = glGetUniformLocation(m_glProgram[TRIANGLE], "orientation"); // Set in changeOrientation(...)
    m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_CHAR1] = glGetUniformLocation(m_glProgram[TRIANGLE], "char1");             // Set here
    m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_SHANENESS] = glGetUniformLocation(m_glProgram[TRIANGLE], "shineness");     // Set here? For now it is hardcoded.
    cout << "m_glProgram[PLANE_3D] = " << m_glProgram[TRIANGLE] << endl;
    cout << "m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_PROJECTION] = " << m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_PROJECTION] << endl;
    cout << "m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_ORIENTATION] = " << m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_ORIENTATION] << endl;
    cout << "m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_CHAR1] = " << m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_CHAR1] << endl;
    cout << "m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_SHANENESS] = " << m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_SHANENESS] << endl;
    if (m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_CHAR1] >= 0)
    {
        GLint char1[4];
        char1[0] = m_projected.chars(0);
        char1[1] = 1;
        char1[2] = m_projected.chars(1);
        char1[3] = m_projected.chars(1, 2);
        cout << "Before setting:       "; for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {cout << char1[i] << ' ';} cout << endl;
        glUniform4iv(m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_CHAR1], 1, char1);

        glGetUniformiv(m_glProgram[TRIANGLE], m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_CHAR1], char1);
        cout << "Read after setting:   "; for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {cout << char1[i] << ' ';} cout << endl;
        glGetUniformiv(m_glProgram[GEOMETRY], m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_CHAR1], char1);
        cout << "Similar for GEOMETRY: "; for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {cout << char1[i] << ' ';} cout << endl;
    }
    if (m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_SHANENESS] >= 0)
    {
        // Add it to configuration. For now it is hardcoded.
        glUniform1f(m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_SHANENESS], 1.0);
    }
}
```

For some reason, the `ivec4 char1` uniform is properly set and can be read from the first shader with `m_glProgram[GEOMETRY]` and uniform `m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_CHAR1]`, but is not properly set in the second shader with `m_glProgram[TRIANGLE]` and uniform `m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_CHAR1]`. The output of this code is:

```
m_glProgram[PLANE_3D] = 5
m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_PROJECTION] = 1262
m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_ORIENTATION] = 1261
m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_CHAR1] = 1263
m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_SHANENESS] = 1264
Before setting:       0 1 1 1 
Read after setting:   0 0 0 0 
Similar for GEOMETRY: 0 1 1 1
```

That means that the prepared vector `[0, 1, 1, 1]` is properly set in the first shader / program and not in the second. The query for its value returned default value `[0, 0, 0, 0]`. What is wrong here?

Comment: This question needs an SSCCE, I'm pretty sure the problematic part has been omitted.

Comment: @Rabbid76, obviously I did it, and the code sample clearly shows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a uniform variable by [`glUniform4iv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml), then the shader program has to installed as part of current rendering state, because `glUniform4iv` sets a value to the default uniform block of the current shader program object. See [`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml).

`TRIANGLE` is the index of a shader program object stored in the container `m_glProgram`, but not a shader program object itselfe.

This means that `glUseProgram(TRIANGLE)` doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Change it to:

```
glUseProgram(m_glProgram[TRIANGLE]);
```

Comment: Of course, I set each program active before setting their uniforms.`glUseProgram(m_glProgram[GEOMETRY]); glUniform4iv(m_glUniform[GEOMETRY_CHAR1], 1, char1); glUseProgram(TRIANGLE); glUniform4iv(m_glUniform[PLANE_3D_CHAR1], 1, char1);` initialize the `char1` for both shaders / programs.

Comment: @AlexandruPopa `glUseProgram(m_glProgram[TRIANGLE]);`